# Pass a maven -D parameter to a java class?

Tags: java, maven

What's is the best approach to use `mvn` to pass custom parameters to a class?

Example :

```
    ~ mvn clean verify -DparamHere=QA1
```

```
    // Pseudo code : I need to pass a param for ${paramHere}

    @Config.Sources({"classpath:${paramHere}.properties"})
    public interface EnvConfig extends Config { 
     // code here
    }
```

I can use TestNG @Parameters, but I am running a JUNIT test so - TestNG is a no go for me.

Comment: What does the documentation for the code that actually interprets the `@Config.Sources` annotation say you can do?

Comment: The variable ${mypath} would be expanded from the System properties or from the environment properties.

Quite frankly - I don't know what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: You can still pass the variable via `-DparamHere` out of the box. 
At least in my case @Config.Sources knows where to parse the param.